# How to pass data to client using React redux and socket.io?

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io, react-redux, redux-thunk

I wasn't familiar with socket.io or other server things until this moment, so maybe I'm struggling with very simple thing.

This is server.js:

```
let socket = null;

export const connect = (stockSymbol) => {
    socket = io('http://localhost:4000');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected');

    socket.on(stockSymbol, (data) => {
        tickData(data);
    });

    socket.emit('ticker', stockSymbol);
});

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('disconnected');
});
};
```

And this is actions:

```
export const TICK_DATA = 'TICK_DATA_ACTION';
export const tickData = data => {
    console.log(data, 'works here');
    return dispatch => {
        console.log(data, 'but doesnt work here');
        dispatch({ type: TICK_DATA, payload: data });
    };
};
```

The problem is that action is triggered, but dispatch function doesn't work. I think there is some problem with binding dispatch object, but I have no idea how to implement it correctly to server file.
Please, share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the **dispatch** function as a parameter from the react component you're invoking the connect function and execute **dispatch(tickData(data));**

```
let socket = null;

export const connect = (dispatch,stockSymbol) => {
socket = io('http://localhost:4000');

socket.on('connect', () => {
console.log('connected');

socket.on(stockSymbol, (data) => {
    dispatch(tickData(data));
});

socket.emit('ticker', stockSymbol);
});

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
console.log('disconnected');
});
};
```

Comment: but data is being passed not from the component, but from service.js

Comment: understood, but I would recommend you call connect() from a react component or an action once when the app starts to avoid complexity, otherwise, you will no be able to access the dispatch since is part of react-redux, you could try to save the dispatch in a window variable when the component is mounted but I'm not totally sure it would work.